# CORS error when accessing microservice API from frontend in production

Tags: c#, .net, vue.js, nginx, cors

I have a microservice-based application that works seamlessly in a development environment, but I'm facing CORS issues in production. When my frontend tries to send a request to the ApiGateway, I receive the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://apigateway/get_all_urls' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

To resolve this, I've made the following changes:

**1. Backend Changes:**
In both my services and the API gateway, I've added the following CORS configuration:

```cs
builder.Services.AddCors();

// ... other app build configurations ...

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(p =>
{
    p.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader();
});
```

**2. Frontend Server Configuration:**
My frontend runs on an Nginx server. I've updated the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file with the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        # Preflight request handling
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        # Regular request headers
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

**Diagnostic Steps:**
To check the connectivity, I executed a `curl` command from within the frontend container:

```bash
curl -v http://apigateway/get_all_urls
```

The response was as expected.

Despite these configurations, the CORS error persists. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Also, I Use .NET for backend and VueJS and TypeScript for fronted.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the order in your pipeline

```
builder.Services.AddCors();

// ... other app build configurations ...

app.UseCors(p =>
{
    p.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader();
});

app.UseRouting();
```